# Is it possible to get recordType from RecentlyViewed SOQL?

Tags: soql, recentlyviewed

Is this possible?

`SELECT Name FROM RecentlyViewed WHERE Type = 'foo' and Type.RecordType.Name = 'bar'`

If yes, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId,RecordType.Name
FROM RecentlyViewed 
WHERE Type IN ('Account', 'Contact')
ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
```

If the Type of object has recordtype then recordtypeId will be displayed otherwise it will be null.

Refer [RecentlyViewed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_RecentlyViewed.htm)